# Upper-half space model of $\text{H}_3$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, hyperbolic-geometry

Does $SL(2,\mathbb{C})\times SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ have a natural (unitary) left-action on $\mathcal{L}^2(\text{H}^{+}_{3})$?

If $G$ is a unimodular Lie group and $K$ is a compact subgroup, $G\times G$ has a unitary left-action on $\mathcal{L}^2(G)$ and merely a left-action on $\mathcal{L}^2(G/K)$. Since $G = SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ is a unimodular Lie group, it seems that $SL(2,\mathbb{C})\times SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ has a unitary left-action on $\mathcal{L}^2(\text{Fr}(\text{H}_3)) = \mathcal{L}^2(SL(2,\mathbb{C}))$ and not on $\mathcal{L}^2(\text{H}_3)$. However, I am not sure if it is still the case for $V = \mathcal{L}^2(\text{H}^{+}_{3})$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$G$ has a natural left action on $\mathcal{L}^2(G/K)$ (and this action is unitary), but no natural right action. Note that for $G=SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ and $K=SU(2,\mathbb{C})$, the quotient $G/K$ equals $\text{H}^{+}_{3}$. Hence $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ has a natural left action on $\mathcal{L}^2(\text{H}^{+}_{3})$ (and this action is unitary), but no natural right action.

Comment: But what about $SL(2,\mathbb{C})\times SL(2,\mathbb{C})$? Does it have a unitary natural left-action on $\mathcal{L}^2(\text{H}^{+}_{3})$?

Comment: @Supergravity I don't think so. When I wrote my answer, I had left-right action in mind, but I cannot think of any other natural action.

Comment: Does it also follow that $SL(2, \mathbb{C})\times SL(2, \mathbb{C})$ has no natural left-action on $\mathcal{L}^2(\text{H}^{+}_{3})$, even if we weaken unitarity condition?

Comment: @Supergravity Well, "natural" is a subjective term. A trivial action is when the pair $(g,h)$ acts like $g$ acts, but I would not call this "natural".

Comment: By natural, I refer to a non-trivial action (neglecting the cases like you described)

Comment: @Supergravity Good question. I guess the answer is negative, but I would not know off-hand how to prove it.